# Address family not supported by protocol for GRPC Netty

Tags: java, grpc, netty

I'm getting the following error when deployed to a remote host:

```
Wrapped by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: connect(..) failed: Address family not supported by protocol: /somegrpcservice-grpc.abc.com:443
Wrapped by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:271)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:252)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:165)
```

I'm deploying using a fatjar, when run locally everything fine.  It is only when the service is deployed to a remote host.  Some things I've already tried:

- Various version of **io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded** from 1.30.0 to 1.53.0
- Running Ncat from the remote host and successfully connecting
- Setting system property:  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

None of these seemed to make a difference.  Appreciate if anyone else has any ideas.  Thanks!

Comment: Describe more of how you're making a fatjar. See https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/9387

Comment: Using gradle and [shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution for my particular case here:

[gRPC UnsupportedAddressTypeException, but only when packaged with shadowJar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73286776/grpc-unsupportedaddresstypeexception-but-only-when-packaged-with-shadowjar)

Apparently my fat jar was being packaged incorrectly and I needed to use the [`mergeServiceFiles()` function](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/merging/#merging-service-descriptor-files) from shadowJar in order to merge my service files.